# How can I add a GiftShip message to packing slip template in Shopify?

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

Long shot, but this is for anyone familiar with the GiftShip app within Shopify.

We are trying to populate our packing slip template with the gift message a user enters on the product page. We already have a customer notes section on our cart page, but requires a user to go back in their checkout process (the flow is pretty terrible in our store template).

The code in our packing slip to display this customer note on the packing slip is as follows:

```
{% if properties.note != blank %}
    <div class="notes">
      <p class="subtitle-bold to-uppercase">
        Notes
      </p>
      <p class="notes-details">
        {{ properties.note }}
      </p>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```

So far, I have tried numerous variables in place of `properties.note` such as `properties.Message` and `attributes.Message`.

Gift ship has been relatively useless when it comes to answering support requests so I am turning here because I know the community on here is great and super helpful.

If I am unclear at all with my request, please let me know and I can explain further.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that Gift Messages can be applied to your order. On a **per product** basis, or a **per order** basis.

If your Gift Messages are associated with **each product** in your order, they will come through as line item properties. You can access your Gift Message as a line item property by writing something like this:

```
{% for line_item in line_items %}

{% for property in line_item.properties %}

{% if property.first == "Gift Message" %}

<p>{{ property.first }}: {{ property.last }}</p>

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

If your Gift Messages are associated with **each order**, you will need to use Shopify's app, Order Printer, in order to get the Gift Message to come through. For some reason Shopify does not allow access to its cart attributes in its packing slip template. When using order printer, the Gift Message can be accessed by this one line of code:

```
Message: {{ attributes.Message }}<br/>
```

I'd recommend reaching out to Shopify Support with a question as to why their cart attributes aren't accessible when when customizing packing slips, but they are pretty much everywhere else in their email templates if your Gift Messages are coming through on a per order basis.

Hope this helps!